# Is there any way i can place models down like blocks in games?

Tags: objects, interface

Okay this is kind weird but pretty much,
Is there a way to place down models like you can place down blocks in games such as minecraft and others?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to point'n'click and place them?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The closest you can get is Shift+F to navigate with first person. If you're a python wizard you might be able to do it. Shift + D is pretty darn close, though you'll have to move you're mouse a bit.

Comment: Like the only way i can explain is with Minecraft; in there you can choose a block from your inventory and place down the block

Comment: Short answer - no, it's not possible. Medium answer - you can use Snapping tools or some add-on (can't remember name) to place blocks accurately. Long... Well, last answer - probably you could do it in Blender Game Engine, but this isn't be easy. Check maybe this thread (it's about UE4) to have an idea what you will need to do to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag a new window from the handle on the top left of the viewport. Make it a 3d view window and position it next to the other 3d view window. Then, build up a library of props and set them off to the side in the second window.

I would enable snapping just to make it more like Minecraft at this point. Now, just copy and past from one window to the other, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to center the object in the middle of the construction area.

[image: yeah...]